# Floating list beside an image

Tags: html, css

It it possible to achieve the following layout in CSS using a `<ul></ul>` and an `<img />` ?

```
|-------------| (li) (li) (li) (li) (li)
|             | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|             | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|             | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|    image    | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|             | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|             | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|-------------| (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
 (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) (li)
 (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) (li)
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CFHru/); I have tried using `float`, `inline-block` and `display:table`, but whenever the number of `<li>` elements exceed the allowed space, the whole list is shifted below the image. This number is randomly generated every time. Can vary from 1 to 50.

My current HTML is:

```
<img src="" />
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <!-- etc.. -->
</ul>
```

The best layout I got was using `box-sizing` some `padding`:

```
|-------------| (li) (li) (li) (li) (li)
|             | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|             | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|             | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|    image    | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|             | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|             | (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
|-------------| (li) (li) (li) (li) (li) 
                (li) (li) (li) (li) (li)
                (li) (li) (li) (li) (li)
                (li) (li) (li) (li) (li)
```

CSS3-based solutions are accepted. Javascript-based solutions are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per i understand write like this:

```
img{
    float:left;
}

ul{
    display:inline;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/CFHru/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to put the `<img>` as one of the `<li>` elements?

Comment: I would, but it's semantically incorrect. The image is used as an illustration and should not take place within my data list.